# How to make bootstrap-datetimepicker to show time in 15 minutes interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

This is my Javascript code to increment in minutes in interval 1

```
fillMinutes = function () {
            var table = widget.find('.timepicker-minutes table'),
                currentMinute = viewDate.clone().startOf('h'),
                html = [],
                row = $('<tr>'),
                step = options.stepping === 1 ? 5 : options.stepping;

            while (viewDate.isSame(currentMinute, 'h')) {
                if (currentMinute.minute() % (step * 4) === 0) {
                    row = $('<tr>');
                    html.push(row);
                }
                row.append('<td data-action="selectMinute" class="minute' + (!isValid(currentMinute, 'm') ? ' disabled' : '') + '">' + currentMinute.format('mm') + '</td>');
                currentMinute.add(step, 'm');
            }
            table.empty().append(html);
        }
```

I want to modify this to increment in 15 minutes interval.
Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Maybe with `step = 15`...I don't know...can you post a complete sample on codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: @Hackerman- It is linked in different places(css, cshtml and controller pages), couldn't able to add it here.....let me try that step=15

Comment: @Hackerman- This doesn't workout

Comment: It was just a guess....like I said, without more info there is nothing to do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
incrementMinutes: function () {
                    var newDate = date.clone().add(15, 'm');
                    if (isValid(newDate, 'm')) {
                        setValue(newDate);
                    }
                }



decrementMinutes: function () {
                    var newDate = date.clone().subtract(15, 'm');
                    if (isValid(newDate, 'm')) {
                        setValue(newDate);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 12):

The option for `stepping` is what I believe you want, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#yourTimePickerElement').datetimepicker({
            stepping: 15
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

Here is the documentation for `stepping`:

**stepping**

> Default: 1

*Number of minutes the up/down arrow's will move the minutes value in the time picker*

---

[Bootstrap 3 Datepicker documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#stepping)

Comment: Thanks for the supporting document too

Comment: Actually making changes to Stepping=15 is affecting hours(code broken). So, I made changes to increment and decrement functions like I answered below.